# gulp-changed with gulp-concat not working

Tags: gulp, less, gulp-concat, gulp-changed

I want to compile only the `.less` files that have changed in order to speed up my debug/coding workflow.

Here is my gulp task:

```
gulp.src('core/**/*.less')
  .pipe(changed('core'))
  .pipe(less().on('error', handleError))
  .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
  .pipe(remember())
  .pipe(concat('main.min.css'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('core'))
  .on('end', resolve)
  .on('error', reject);
```

I used `gulp-changed` and because it didn't work at first, I tried to use `gulp-remember` as well, but with no effect. The watch works, it compiles super fast, but it has no effect at all.

If I remove `changed('core')` and `remember()` it works, but it's slower (around 16 seconds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gulp-changed` is a poor fit for your use case, since it is meant to compare input files with output files on disk.

Say you have an input file `core/foo/bar.less` that you pipe through `changed('dist')`. What this does is to look for an output file `dist/foo/bar.less`. If the input file is newer than the output file, it is passed through. Otherwise it is filtered out.

That means using `changed('core')` cannot possibly work. It compares the input file `core/foo/bar.less` with the output file `core/foo/bar.less`. **But they're the same file**. That means the input file can **never** be newer than the output file and is never passed through.

There's another problem. You don't have one output file for each input file. All your `.less` files are compiled into **one** `main.min.css` file. While you can make this work using a [custom comparator](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed#haschanged) it doesn't work out of the box.

What you actually want is [`gulp-cached`](https://github.com/contra/gulp-cached). Instead of comparing each input file with an output file on disk it compares each input file with a previous version of the same file that has been cached in memory.

```
var cached = require('gulp-cached');

gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src('core/**/*.less')
    .pipe(cached('less'))
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
    .pipe(remember('less'))
    .pipe(concat('main.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('core'));
});
```

Comment: Very well explained. I have to assume that I didn't really take the time to understand precisely how gulp-changed / gulp-remember / gulp-cached works. I just saw some tutorial explaining that gulp-changed is nice and some code sample and I totally misunderstand the basis. Your explanation is very clear and precise, thank you very much for the time that you take to answer me. It works, but I will improve my knowledge of this cached/remember in order to avoid issues with it later ;-)