# gulp less compile only changed file

Tags: gulp, less, gulp-watch, gulp-changed

i have problem, when i run gulp watch -> run task styles:build, and all of my less files was recompile. How i can compile only changed file?

```
gulp.task('styles:build', function () {
    return gulp.src(pathes.src.styles)
        .pipe(changed(pathes.build.styles), {extension: '.css'})
        .pipe(print(function(filepath) {
            return "➔ file was changed: " + filepath;
        }))
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(less({
            plugins: [autoprefix, cleanCSSPlugin],
            paths: ['./', 'web/styles']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pathes.build.styles))
});


gulp.task('watch', function() {
   gulp.watch(pathes.src.styles, ['styles:build'])
});
```

[image]

Comment: Does it run through all the files each time you make a change to a less file or only the first time,when 'watch' task is first run?  I believe it is expected behavior that the first time all the files will pass through gulp-changed.

Comment: @Mark any changes start compile all files, for example i add '; or &nbsp, any changes' and than run full task styles:build

Comment: You need another close paren ) at the end of the changed pipe.

Comment: @Mark can you write example?

Comment: .pipe(changed(pathes.build.styles), {extension: '.css'}))  <-- note I have added another close parenthesis at the end.  Try that change and see if it helps although I would think you be getting errors without it.

Comment: @mark With brackets all okay

Comment: If that fixed it for you, I'll put it into an answer.

Comment: @mark - i mean -all okay with bracket)  

There are no superfluous brackets, everything is open and closed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151540/discussion-between-mark-and-dmitriy-lishtvan).

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the line below to add a closing parenthsis:

```
.pipe(changed(pathes.build.styles, {extension: '.css'}))
```

Also as I cautioned the first time the task is run it probably will pass through all files.

Comment: .pipe(changed(pathes.build.styles, {extension: '.css'})) - that write, but it still work badly

Comment: Then I would try gulp-cached, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113942/gulp-changed-with-gulp-concat-not-working

Comment: Ok i'll try later, i need go too sleep

Comment: cached -help me, now compile only changed file, but i have new problem)) cache don't see import less files, when i change file - he compile, but main file was the same

Answer (score 0):

i think i found solution
just install lessChanged = require('gulp-less-changed')
and include him before less pipe

```
.pipe(lessChanged())
.pipe(less())
```